# Wordpress plugin for anonymous comments

Tags: wordpress, plugins, comments

for my temporary wedding website, I'm looking for a plugin which allows unsubscribed users to insert a small and simple comments inside a blogpost. I know about the issue with spam and stuff, but as mentioned, the page will be offline again in a couple of months.
Target is that our guests can tell the DJ their favourite music, in previous and during the party.

Commenting was the most obvious solution to me, but neither native function nor additional plugins hitted the target. The closest plugin was [POWr Comments](https://wordpress.org/plugins/powr-comments/), but you have to subscribe a plan for anonymous comments.

Problem was also, that the native comment box is only shown if the user is viewing the blogpost as 'standalone' and not in this list of blogs, what we are using. Sorry for wording, no idea how to describe it better. You want me to link the page?

Thank for every hint!

Answer (score 1):

You can make the name and email field optional by going to "Settings" then "Discussion" and uncheck the box next to "Comment author must fill out name and e-mail." Then commenting is open to anyone without needing to make an account.

Source/Other Solutions: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-allow-users-to-post-anonymous-comments-in-wordpress/

Or if you prefer here is a Plugin that may work as well: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpdiscuz/

More commenting information: codex.wordpress.org/Comments_in_WordPress

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately the native comment system doesn't work for me because it's only shown if users select the "read more" button and get directed to the page of this post. But I want to have it on the first page where the collection of all the posts are located.